# MySQL doesn't accept loop end instruction

Tags: mysql, loops, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger after an insert event; this is the definition of the trigger:

```
 BEGIN
    DECLARE stud INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cd INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE sw CURSOR FOR 
        (SELECT CodiceStudente FROM Listastudenticorsi WHERE CodiceCorso IN
            (SELECT CodiceCorso FROM Listanews WHERE CodiceNews IN
                (SELECT MAX(Codice) FROM News)));
    DECLARE cod CURSOR FOR
        (SELECT CodiceDocente FROM Listanews WHERE CodiceNews IN
               (SELECT MAX(Codice) FROM News));
    OPEN sw;
    OPEN cod;
    get_loop: LOOP
    FETCH sw INTO stud;
    FETCH cod INTO cd;
    INSERT INTO Inbox(Mittente, Destinatario, Oggetto, Contenuto, Data) VALUES (cd, stud, "Nuova news", "", CURDATE());
    END LOOP get_loop;
END
```

For some reasons, MySQL doesn't let me create it: it says that I have to check the syntax near "LOOP; END" at line 17, but as far as I know the syntax over there is correct... I don't understand what's wrong, even if I put the name of the loop after the end loop, the error shows up.

I'm not sure whether the error might be in the INSERT instruction: I'm not sure about the use of the variable @cod; it is always a unique value, but I'm not sure if it's that that is causing the problem. If it's that, how may I change that instruction in order to get the same result?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `END IF;` statement on line 17

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE stud VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE sw CURSOR FOR 
        (SELECT CodiceStudente FROM Listastudenticorsi WHERE CodiceCorso IN
            (SELECT CodiceCorso FROM Listanews WHERE CodiceNews IN
                (SELECT MAX(Codice) FROM News)));

    SET @cod = (SELECT CodiceDocente FROM Listanews WHERE CodiceNews IN
               (SELECT MAX(Codice) FROM News));
    OPEN sw;
    get_loop: LOOP
    FETCH sw INTO stud;
        IF done THEN
        LEAVE get_loop;
        END IF;
    INSERT INTO Inbox(Mittente, Destinatario, Oggetto, Contenuto, Data) VALUES (@cod, @i, stud, "", CURDATE());
    END LOOP get_loop;
END;
```

Comment: I'm writing it inside a Phpmyadmin dialog box, so it is not needed

Comment: Same output as before:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LOOP;
END' at line 20

Comment: Add loop name to the `END` statement.

Comment: Same :( , even adding the loop name

Comment: You're missing the END IF; statement. MySQL is looking for the END statement of the IF branch you've opened. But you're only giving the END LOOP statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are getting that error, but you don't need a `loop` at all.  Just do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Inbox(Mittente, Destinatario, Oggetto, Contenuto, Data)
    SELECT @cod, CodiceStudente, 'Nuova news', '', CURDATE()
    FROM Listastudenticorsi
    WHERE CodiceCorso IN (SELECT CodiceCorso 
                          FROM Listanews
                          WHERE CodiceNews IN (SELECT MAX(Codice) FROM News));
```

Comment: Yeah, but this code is not doing what I want: I want to switch '@i' on the rows I get from a previous SELECT statement, and in order to do that I need to perform a loop... I don't know other solutions :/

Comment: @tenik . . . The value of `@i` is not changing in the code in your question.  Answers can only be based on the information in questions, but I'm pretty sure you do not need a cursor or a loop.

Comment: I'm sorry, I deleted it while copying the code here.

Comment: I've just updated the code, using the correct version.

Comment: @tenik . . . The code is unstable.  You are fetching results from two queries with no `order by`, so the results can arrive in any order.